# How to manage quality of an image with gem MiniMagik

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, prawn

I'm working on an App which gets shipment labels from Express Carriers in Ruby on Rails 4. At the moment I´m working with the UPS API and its label which is GIF image. 
To be able to generate the PDF containing the GIF label I'm using Prawn which not support GIF. So the GIF is converted to a PNG. I´m able to have the label but when I print it out the quality is very low and difficult to read what is inside the label. 
I need to understand how to add a better quality as otherwise, the label is not possible to use it.

The class I'm working on:

```
class UPSLabelConsolidation
  attr_reader :base64_encoded_gif_labels

  def initialize(base64_encoded_gif_labels)
    @base64_encoded_gif_labels = base64_encoded_gif_labels
  end

  def perform!
    identifier = SecureRandom.hex(3)

    tmp_label_files = base64_encoded_gif_labels.each_with_index.map do |base64_encoded_gif_label, index|
      tmp_label_file = Tempfile.new(["ups-label-#{identifier}-#{index}", ".png"], Rails.root.join("tmp"))
      tmp_label_file.binmode

      image = MiniMagick::Image.read(Base64.decode64(base64_encoded_gif_label), "gif")

      image.combine_options do |b|
        b.rotate "90" # Rotate 90-degrees clockwise
        b.crop "800x1000+0+0" # Crop ~200px whitespace from the bottom of the label
      end

      image.format("png") # Prawn does not support GIF, so we convert it here.
      image.write(tmp_label_file.path)

      tmp_label_file.rewind

      tmp_label_file
    end

    new_page = false
    @pdf = Prawn::Document.new(page_size: [297, 390], margin: 20, page_layout: :portrait) # Margin is ~0.7cm

    tmp_label_files.each do |label_file|
      @pdf.start_new_page if new_page
      @pdf.image label_file, width: 250, position: :left # Width is ~8.8cm
      new_page = true
    end
  end

  def write!(path)
    if @pdf
      @pdf.render_file(path)
    else
      raise "`#perform!` before `#write!`"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to provide a larger density than the default when reading the PDF file so that it is rasterized at a larger pixel dimension. If needed, you can then resize to a smaller dimension.

Comment: Could you please explain me how to do that or what I need to look because I am not sure what to do

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post. I thought your were converting from PDF to GIF. But on reading again, it looks like you are trying to convert from GIF to PDF. So my comment above is not relevant.

Comment: @Jakub I know it's an old topic but did you manage it? I've got the same bad quality picture with Prawn.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't work anymore with prawn so I don't remember this issue anymore